# Flutter Web - create a new line in multiline TextField with shift + enter(return)

Tags: flutter

```
TextField(
      onEditingComplete: () {
        FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();
      },
      textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
      keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
      controller: tagsController,
      minLines: 1,
      maxLines: 10
    );
```

A flutter web problem.

Multiline textfield. With enter(return) I complete editing and with focusManager can leave the field.

But shift enter do exactly the same instead of starting a new line.

If I remove FocusManager, then I cant leave textfield by pressing enter(return) so cursor stays active but then I can create a new line with both enter and sift enter.